# How do I find out if I have pressed the checkbutton?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.config(background="green")
window.bind("<Escape>", quit)
cbttn = Checkbutton(text="Caps?").grid(row=3, column=0)
```

Does `if cbttn = True` work for it? Or do I have to move the `.grid()` function and move it to the next line of code.

Answer (score 1):

An assignment such as:

```
cbttn = Checkbutton(text="Caps?").grid(row=3, column=0)
```

yields in **cbttn** being of an object of *None* type.

Either remove the assignment to cbttn (if you do not want to reference it further in the script)

```
Checkbutton(text="Caps?").grid(row=3, column=0)
```

or move grid to a new line as:

```
cbttn = Checkbutton(text="Caps?")
cbttn.grid(row=3, column=0)
```

And to see if the Checkbutton was pressed or not, use the *command* option available. Check the example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_checkbutton.htm). Taking this example:

```
from tkinter import *

def display():
    print(CheckVar1.get())

top = Tk()
CheckVar1 = IntVar()
CheckVar2 = IntVar()
C1 = Checkbutton(top, text = "Music", variable = CheckVar1, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=5, \
                 width = 20, command = display)
C2 = Checkbutton(top, text = "Video", variable = CheckVar2, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=5, \
                 width = 20)
C1.pack()
C2.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

The output should keep switching between **0** and **1**

Comment: But how do I find out if it has been clicked or not if I want to use it in an if, elif command?

Comment: @PeterGalibaYear7 I edited the answer. You don't need to use _if..elif..else_ for Checkbuttons. Hope this clarifies it

Comment: It makes sense now

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/coding folder/alphabet_draw0.1.0.py", line 39, in <module>
    text=Label(text=cbttn.variable)
AttributeError: 'Checkbutton' object has no attribute 'variable'